# Opening an Intent of another app (getLaunchIntentForPackage()) always return to first activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem in redirecting the activity after calling an intent of other app using `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage`.

Let's say I have an "A" app and "B" app.

In app "A", A1 is my activity launcher. From A1, I navigate to A2 Activity and calling an intent to app "B"

My problem is, after doing some task in activity B, and want to return back to app "A", why its always go to activity "A1" not "A2" where the intent of App "B" is calling from. I want it to return to caller intent not the first intent.

Anyone know the trick?

my code is shown below:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xx.yyyy");
if (LaunchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Please help me to solve the matters and your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are finishing the activity A2:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xx.yyyy");
if (LaunchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    finish(); // HERE... You are finishing A2
}
```

Just remove that `finish();`